# Node.js, Запрос сервера на клиент. Как ответить всем кто в комнате или просто всем?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Знакомлюсь с node.js, использую библиотеку socket.io

Возник такой вопрос как ответить всем пользователям и ответить всем пользователям в комнате?

Из документации вычитал:

```
io.sockets.emit('message', "this is a test"); // не работает

io.sockets.to(room).emit('message', 'all test'); // не работает
```

Но к сожалению это не работает. Никаких ошибок нет. В свою очередь ответить всем кроме текущего и ответ текущему пользователю работает без проблем.

Подскажите пожалуйста почему не работают ответы всем и всем из конкретной комнаты ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что бы ответить пользователям конкретной комнаты на сервере нужно выполнить следующее:

```
io.sockets.in(socket.room).emit("addmessage",message);
```

и соответственно на клиенте нужно обработать событие addmessage

```
socket.on("addmessage",function(message){});
```

и всем пользователям:

```
io.sockets.broadcast.emit("updatechat",message);
```

и обработать на клиенте. А вообще [вот](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki) хорошая литература.

Comment: Будьте внимательны к версиям socket.io, я немного помучился с `io.sockets.socket(to).emit();`, которая как оказалось уже не поддерживается в версии 1.0

Answer (score 0):

[Создаем чат на Node.js и Socket.IO](http://habrahabr.ru/post/127525/)
`socket.broadcast.send` — отправка сообщения всем клиентам, кроме текущего